# Is Cardboard sdk open source?

Tags: sdk, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I'm new to VR development,and i am do some investigation about cardboard sdk,could any guys tell me if cardboard sdk open source? And if open ,Where could I find the head tracking source code in cardboard sdk?

Comment: No: https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-java/issues/11

Answer (score 0):

> Is cardboard sdk open source?

Well, NO. As @birryree shared in this link: https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-java/issues/11.

But, you can find the head tracking c# code in **CardboardHead.cs** located in *yourProject/Assets/Cardboard/Scripts/* after you import **CardboardSDKForUnity** package in your project. Or you can simply double click on component shown in the image below:

### [image]

> And, you can refer Decompiled CardboardSDK 0.5.1 source code here:
>   https://github.com/rsanchezsaez/cardboard-java